# Passing strings from C++ to C# (and vice versa)

Tags: c#, c++, com, unmanaged, managed

I am following the example in [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736) to call a .NET DLL from native C++ code. The code for C# looks like this:

```
public class StringExample: IStringExample
{
    public string returnString(string input)
    {   
        return input;
    }
}
```

I followed the example's steps to build, register the COM assembly, and export the type library (.tlb) from the C# code.

In C++ code, I am trying to use code similar to the following:

```
#import "..\StringExample\bin\Debug\StringExample.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace StringExample;

void abc()
{
  // Initialize COM.
  HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

  // Create the interface pointer.
  IStringExample ptr(__uuidof(StringExample));

  BSTR bstrInput = L"hello world";
  BSTR bstrOutput =L"";

  ptr->returnString(bstrInput, &bstrOutput);

  TCHAR* szOutput = (TCHAR *)_bstr_t(bstrOutput);

  // Uninitialize COM.
  CoUninitialize();
}
```

However, bstrOutput is empty. Moreover, I need to convert the bstrOutput to TCHAR* to pass it to a different api.

Is there an error in the variable initialization? Is there a different way to pass string variables between .NET and C++?

Comment: One thing you must never, *never*, **never** do is ignore the return value of a COM call.  Many things can go wrong, the HRESULT tells you about it.  Use the FAILED or SUCCEEDED macros, use IErrorInfo to obtain a description of the mishap.  Favor the #import directive to make this all automatic.

Comment: I'm not sure understand your problem. What I get is you have a C# class with a function which gets a string and return another one. you juts want to call in from your c++ code and print the result. Am I correct?

Comment: Your input value is illegal. `L"hello world"` is not a `BSTR`; it's a wchar_t string. The C++ compiler can't distinguish between the two, so you have to be really careful. Learn about [BSTRs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx) as well as the [list of BSTR functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221105.aspx) in MSDN. Read every sentence carefully; BSTRs follow very specific rules and you must obey all of them. Also, listen to Hans' advice about the return value of COM calls.